How to do moderated mediation analysis with linear mixed model with nested random effect?
I want to build a model like this. All variables are continuous variables. Each subject was measured for many times  across days, so this should be done with a linear mixed model I guess. What's more, the X,Y are measured only once in each trial while the Med are measured by different channels in each trial, so for the X-M, the random effect are nested.

It's a little complicated. To make it clearer, I will write the supposed model of each path:
c_path = lmer(Y ~  cX + (1|subject/channel) + (1|day) + (1|time), data= rating_RR)

a_path = lmer(Med ~ aX + (1|subject/channel) + (1|day) + (1|time), data= rating_RR)

b_path = lmer(Y ~  c'X + bMed*time + (1|subject/channel) + (1|day), data= rating_RR) 

I have searched so many tutorials and Q&A, but didn't find a way to do this. The R packagebruceR::PROCESScould add random effect, but sadly it can only contain one random variable(if I didn't misunderstand it).
I wonder whether it's realizable and how to do it. Thanks!

Can anyone help me.......
